# dynamically enabling/disabling a input text from controller

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I'm new in PHP and im using CI :D
Now i have a view `user_form_v` and its controller `user`
in my controller i tried to pass a string variable name `$validate` and i will validate it in my view with javascript, so if `$validate == add` i will enable my input text.
This is my javascript(NOT WORKING) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validation(){
            var temp = <?php echo $validate?>
            if (temp == "add")document.getElementById("id").disable = false;
        }
    </script>
```

and this is my input text, the default is DISABLED :

```
<input id="id" type="text" name="ID_user" class="text" disabled="disable"
                value="<?php echo (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>
```

**ANSWER :**
According to the choosen answer, Javascript is no needed here(sorry im a noob) so all we need to do is add this : `<?php if($validate!='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>` this way, my input text will be disabled if they choose update.
**However it cant be work with `disabled="disabled"`**(I dont know why)
So this is the final code for dynamic input text : `<input type="text" name="ID_user" class="text"
                    <?php if($validate!='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>
                    value="<?php echo (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In your javascript:

- `.disabled` not `.disable`
- wrap your PHP in quotes.
- are you making a call to `validation()`? If not, this code will never execute.

### In your html:

`disabled="disabled"` not `disabled="disable"`

### Update after your comments:

Are you sure there is even a need for javascript here *at all*? I mean, you seem to be allowing the client to make decisions that the server would be happy to do.

`<input id="id" type="text" name="ID_user" class="text" value="<?= $user['ID_user']?>" <? if($validate!=='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>/>`

And scrap the javascript all together. (I dropped your `isset()` call, throw it back in if you really need it)

Comment: Thanks but it still not working..my input text still dont change to enabled

Comment: You need to call the `validation()` method, you've only 'set it up'.

Comment: Thanks.
I tried 'onLoad="validation();"', but why nothing happened?(and no errors)

Comment: This is what i tried:
i delete all the javascript stuff  and i change my html code to this:
'<input id="id" type="text" name="ID_user" class="text" disabled="disabled"
     <?php if($validate!=='add'){echo "disabled";} ?>
     value="<?php echo (isset($user['ID_user']))?$user['ID_user']:""?>"/>'
But still nothing happened
Sorry im noob in web development

Comment: Then, `$validate` must not contain the 'add' string. Inspect the source of the page; How is the browser rendering the `<input.../>`?

Comment: Just to make this clear, i have 2 different functions : insert and update
If insert is pressed then $validate = "add";
If update then $validate = "update";
And if the user choose insert i will enable my input text, but if the user choose update then i will disable my input text(id cant be edited)
Thanks for your help :D

Comment: i think it should be  <?php if($validate!='add'){echo "disabled";} ?> because it means the user want to update the data and i need to disable the input text.
However, things still not working until now @_@
What do you mean by echo "disabled"?can that code change my input text state from disable to enable?Thanks :D

Comment: The disabled tag can be singular. It does not require a key value pair - see: http://jsfiddle.net/j2vTG/1

Comment: ITS WORKING..i just need to delete  disabled="disabled"...and after that i use your code and its working :D
Thanks for your passion :D

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around it

```
var temp = "<?php echo $validate ?>";
```

so it will result to

```
var temp = "add";
```

and not

```
var temp = add; // Error: undefined variable add
```

Comment: Thank you, but why is it still not working?
i tried 'if (temp == "add")document.getElementById("id").disabled = "enable";' and 'if (temp == "add")document.getElementById("id").disabled = false;' but my input text is still cant be enabled

Comment: combine my answer with Jordan's